# iOS - GA - library not found

Tags: ios, build, google-analytics, static-libraries

I am trying to add Google Analytics to my iOS app. I followed the step of Google's tutorial but now my projet doesnt compile and I have the following error message.

```
ld: library not found for -lGoogleAnalyticsServices
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I checked and the the library libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a is in my project folder so I dont understand where the problem comes from.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to your project > Build settings > search for the `LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS` and check their paths.

Comment: thanks! I changed it manually and it worked but I put the address for my computer. How do I change it so it works on every computer? Something like $(SRCROOT)/ ?

Answer (score 1):

just put `lGoogleAnalyticsServices.a` near with `myapp.xcodeproj`, and drag library in your frameworks block in `xcode`

Answer (score 0):

I also had this error and was able to fix it like this:

1. Go to the app project settings
2. Go to the General tab
3. Under Linked Frameworks and Libraries, drag libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a to be at the end of the list.

Order matters because if a dependency of said library isn't built first, Xcode won't be able to link it.